# Print Crystal Report to Intermec Printer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, crystal-reports, intermec

I have this situation in which I must print a barcode to a intermec printer (PC43T) and the printer is not installed on the server, as the clients will be using this printing from a web app.

The printer has a ethernet module and we have the Ip and the port (9100 the default one).

As I cannot use PrintToPrinter from the crystal report engine, I've tried to export the report and convert it to a byte array and send it in this way. I've also tried almost all of ExportFormatType formats and still nothing. The printer seems to receive some data but nothing is printed out.

Can you please help me with this issue on how to print crystal report on a remote printer?

I forgot to mention that the communication with the printer is established using client socket and IPEndPoint and it was tested using a .prn file for test and the printer it's working.

Tech stack: VS2017, SAP Crystal report version 13.0

Comment: I'm exporting the report to PDF, while using a simple script that is printing all incoming pdf files via SumatraPFD (https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/). That script is of course running on a server where the appropriate driver is installed.

Comment: But the problem is that I do not know from the server side which printer will be used, I know only the IP and the Port and in the application he is able to choose a template (a report in this case)  which will be printed. Now the problem is not with the generation but how to send the report to the printer using client socket in order to be able to print it.